# How can I display certain page to one group only?

Tags: permissions, groups

I want to create registration form and display it for only anonymous users group
I already make the anonymous users group

Comment: Not really sure what you mean. An anonymous user isn't necessarily an unknown user, it's just a user who isn't currently logged in. If you just don't allow anonymous access they'll be shown the login page which you can customize if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anonymous can't be a group, as it means the person who's not logged in (generally).. Thus if he is not logged in, how can you detect which group user belongs to..

SharePoint already has [Anonymous Access policy](http://www.topsharepoint.com/enable-anonymous-access-in-sharepoint-2010)

If you want the anonymous users to get registered on your SharePoint site, you might need to use Form Based Authentication in order to get these users authenticated.. Let me know if you need further information on this..

**UPDATE**

If you want the **Application page** to be available to Anonymous users you should inherit the page from `UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase`.. see http://www.concurrency.com/blog/allow-anonymous-access-to-sharepoint-application-pages-in-the-_layouts-directory/

Comment: My registration Form is Application page so I need the anonymous user see it

Comment: Please see the update

Comment: @SamarGamil, please mark the answer as correct to close the question :)